# Customize ArgumentError message in initialize method

Tags: ruby, class, overriding, argument-error

Rather than have my Ruby object's constructor complain about the number of arguments given (in the event of bad args), I'd like the message to list what was expected, exactly.

```
def initialize a, b, c
  begin
    @a = a
    @b = b
    @c = c
  rescue ArgumentError
    raise ArgumentError, "my custom error message"
  end
end
```

Obviously this won't work, but hopefully this gets the idea across. I just want to override the default ArgumentError message for this class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def initialze(*args)
  raise ArgumentError, 'my message' unless valid_according_to_my_rules(args)

  @a, @b, @c = args
end
```